# How to modify the node values of a XML file located at server end using PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I need to modify my xml node value like

```
<summary>
<data>125</data>
</summary>
```

to

```
<summary>
<data>200</data>
</summary>
```

I am using PHP 5.2. Although i am able to read the xml files, but i am not able to update it

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'summary.xml' );
$data = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "data" );
$datavalue = $data ->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo "$datavalue\n";
```

How to modify this data node value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using DOMXml and Xpath, to update XML entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671273/using-domxml-and-xpath-to-update-xml-entries) , also please see http://php.net/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the nodeValue and then use `saveXML()`:

```
$data ->item(0)->nodeValue = 200;

$doc->saveXML();
```